# Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'Repeater1'

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, repeater

I have a standard Repeater and all I want to do is add paging to it and I keep getting the error listed in the title. Here is what my error points to

```
 private void ItemsGet()
    {
        // Read sample item info from XML document into a DataSet
        DataSet Items = new DataSet();
        Items.ReadXml(MapPath("Items.xml"));

        // Populate the repeater control with the Items DataSet
        PagedDataSource objPds = new PagedDataSource();
        objPds.DataSource = Items.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        objPds.AllowPaging = true;
        objPds.PageSize = 3;

        objPds.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;

        lblCurrentPage.Text = "Page: " + (CurrentPage + 1).ToString() + " of "
           + objPds.PageCount.ToString();

        // Disable Prev or Next buttons if necessary
        cmdPrev.Enabled = !objPds.IsFirstPage;
        cmdNext.Enabled = !objPds.IsLastPage;

        Repeater1.DataSource = objPds;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
```

for those that will ask I will post my repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemDataBound="myFunction">
        <HeaderTemplate>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>             
        <ItemTemplate>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
        </FooterTemplate>        
    </asp:Repeater>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:label id="lblCurrentPage" runat="server"></asp:label></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your're setting the `DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"` and also setting the `Repeater1.DataSource = objPds;`. Set one or the other.
In your case you probably want to remove the `DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"`